# Convert binary data stored in std::string to wxString

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, binary-data, wxstring

What's the standard way to convert binary data in std::string to a wxString, all the constructors/assignment functions of wxString I've tried so far, even when given a length, are null-terminated which obviously isn't what I want.

Comment: Why do you need to store binary data in a string?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Used in this program later on to write to a file, forced to do std::string to wxString due to how things are structured

Comment: Can you change the encoding? You could use base64 if that's possible.

Comment: @eerorika Not currently, would require a decent bit of a re-work so hoping for an assign function with a length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, [From8BitData](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_string.html#a5aedc23e9cc2774237d99148d0622661) should work.  For example, assuming `str` is of type std::string:

```
wxString str2 = wxString::From8BitData(str.data(), str.length());
```

You could then write this to a file like so (assuming `outputfile` is of type std::ofstream):

```
outputfile.write(str2.To8BitData(), str2.length());
outputfile.close();
```

I'm not sure what you're gaining by the conversion to wxString.  But if you want to do so, that should be how to make the conversion and use the resulting wxString object.

Comment: This works fundamentally, but at some point (still looking) in either the encode or decode, it replaces Unix line endings with Windows

Comment: This replacement happens when writing to a file open in text mode and has nothing to do with `wxString`.

Comment: @VZ.Yeah, caught it. One oddity (which thankfully doesn't break anything for me), is that From8BitData passes back a string with the reserved space size of str.data() and not actual str size